# R - Reason for error when indexing with double brackets beyond the length of a list

Tags: r, indexing, subset

With single brackets, an index greater than a list's length returns a list containing a single element: `NULL`.
Indexing with a non-existent name returns the same.

```
x <- as.list(1:10)

x[11]
# [[1]]
# NULL

x["i"]
# [[1]]
# NULL
```

I would expect indexing with `[[` to return the value `NULL`, as both `x[["i"]]` and `x$i` do. 
However, `[[`-indexing using a numeric value beyond the length of a list returns an error.

```
x[["i"]]
# NULL

x$i
# NULL

x[[11]]
# Error in x[[11]] : subscript out of bounds
```

What is the reason for the difference here? Why throw an error for just this one case, and not when a string index fails to match to an element name?

### Difference from existing questions

To clarify, I am not asking when to use `[` vs. `[[` vs. `$`. I understand that `[[` and `$` can be used for accessing the contents of only a single list element. I am wondering why a numeric index greater than the length of a list fails with an error *for `[[` only*.

Phrased differently: if `x[[11]]` uses a "subscript out of bounds", how come `x[11]` is not doing the same?

I do not see this question as a duplicate. While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-elem) discusses the same operators, none of the answers I've read directly address the `NULL` and error difference I'm asking about.

### Established inconsistency

Looking at section 4.3.3 in [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html#subset-single), I see that this inconsistent behavior is actually well-known. The functions `pluck()` and `chuck()` from `purrr` were invented for exactly this reason. Still, I wonder if anyone can provide some reasoning behind why R would be programmed this way?

Answer (score 0):

When you access a list through `[1]` or `["i"]` you are still working on lists. If you access through `[[1]]` you are retrieving the value inside the first element of the list.

```
l=vector("list",10)
class(l["i"])
[1] "list"
class(l[1])
[1] "list"
class(l[[1]])
[1] "NULL"
```

If we were to test with a list containing a number:

```
l[[1]]=1
class(l[[1]])
[1] "numeric"
```

Summing up, with the first two operators you display what the list *holds* in that specific place. With the `[[]]` you display the thing *itself*.